# Application of Uniform Bounded Principle (UBP)

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $Y$ be a Banach space, and $Z$ be a n.v.s. If $(B_n)_n\in L(E,F)$ with the property that for all $(y_n)_n\in Y$, that $\|y_n\|\rightarrow 0$, we have $\|B_n(y_n)\|\rightarrow 0$. Prove that $\sup_{n}\|B_n\|<\infty$.

So it is sufficient to show that $\sup_{n}\|B_n(y)\|<\infty $ for all $y\in Y$. Any hints on how to achieve this? Should consider constructing a function on $c_0(Y)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that there is some $y$ such that $\sup_n \lVert B_n(y)\rVert= +\infty$. Then there is an increasing sequence of integers $(n_i)_{i\geqslant 1} $ such that for each $i$, $\lVert B_{n_i}(y)\rVert \gt i  $. Now, define a sequence $(y_j)_{j\geqslant 1}$  by $y_j=y/j$ if $j=n_i$ for some $i$ and $y_j= 0$ if $j\notin \{n_i, i\geqslant 1\}   $. In this way, the sequence $(y_j)_{j\geqslant 1}$ converges to $0$ but the sequence $\left(B_{n_i}\left(y_{n_i} \right)\right)_{i\geqslant1 } $ does not converge to $0$.